# Export query results to Excel in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, export-to-excel

I have asp.net MVC app in c# and I get query results(from Entity Framework) and I need to put the data in Excel sheet which user can download. So this is what I am trying to do and I want to know how to write each row of data into excel sheet? Any other approach I should take is welcome too.

```
var certs = CertificateService.ReadAllSentCertificates();
                Application excel = new Application();
                string filePath = "C:/ToDoList/SentStats_" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".xls";

                Workbook mybook = excel.Workbooks.Add();
                excel.Visible = true;
                try
                {
                    mybook.Activate();
                    Worksheet mysheet = mybook.Worksheets.Add();

                     foreach (var x in certs)
                    {
                        // How to write each row in excel??

                    }
                   //mybook.SaveAs(Filename: filepath);
                    mybook.Save();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
                finally
                {
                    mybook.Close();
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use Office interop in a web application. MS Office was never designed to run on a server. If you want to build an Excel sheet you could use [OpenXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh180830.aspx) on the server.

As an alternative you could return a view containing the results in a `<table>` and serve this view with the `application/vnd.ms-excel` `Content-Type` response header. You will have far less control over the formatting of the resulting sheet compared to using the OpenXML SDK which gives you full control.